# PowerPoint Office JS Task Pane Addin functionality to copy and paste shape

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, office-addins, powerpoint-addins, powerpoint-web-addins

I must be missing something, but I cannot seem to figure out how to build a simple function to copy and paste a shape in my Office Addin for PowerPoint. Seems there is no support for this. At least not what I can find in the APIs for PowerPoint. Really hope I am missing something obvious here...

The work around I use at the moment is to copy all available attributes of the shapes I want to copy and then add a new shape with the same attributes. This would be fine (even though cumbersome), but only some attributes are accessible (like height, width etc.). Many text / paragraph formatting attributes are still missing.

Hope someone knows a better way to do this!
Any support will be greatly appreciated!

[error message I receive in ScriptLab:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaD6Z.png)

```js
$("#run").click(run);

function run() {
  Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(Office.CoercionType.XmlSvg, {}, (asyncResult) => {
    if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
      //await context.sync();
      console.error(asyncResult);
    } else {
      //await context.sync();
      console.log(asyncResult);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done with the Common APIs. Try using `document.getSelectedDataAsync` and `setSelectedDataAsync`. The reference for the Common APIs is [office package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office).

Comment: I was hoping for a better solution, but I think you are right that this is the only way available for now. The drawback with the setSelectedDataAsynch for SVGs is that it is not a "real" shape (it is obviously a SVG). Which means that adjustment points and other shape specific attributes are lost in the process. For the getSelectedDataAsynch part I have not been successful in getting the function to return a value. I only get "undefined" returned.

Comment: This is my function as it is written now;   
getSelectedSVG = async () => {
    await PowerPoint.run(async (context) => {
      Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(
        Office.CoercionType.XmlSvg,
        function (result) {
          const dataValue = result.asyncContext as string;
          console.log(dataValue);
          return dataValue as any;
        }
      );
      await context.sync();
    });
  };
My understanding is it should return a string for the XML, but I get only undefined. Any ideas where I go wrong? 
Thanks!

Comment: It would be great if you could reproduce this in the Script Lab tool. If you can, create a gist and provide the URL to the gist.

Comment: Good idea. I get the same issue in ScriptLab as well. Hope you can access the gist the way I provided it! Many thanks for your support!
<script src="https://gist.github.com/ThomasHeron/038f463c41e095d1da11a4f3c56c0c0c.js"></script>
https://gist.github.com/ThomasHeron/038f463c41e095d1da11a4f3c56c0c0c

Comment: ScriptLab is telling me that that is not a valid gist URL. `https://gist.github.com/ThomasHeron/038f463c41e095d1da11a4f3c56c0c0c`

Comment: Strange. I put the link in the ScriptLab import dialogue and it worked for me. I went to github --> Share --> Copy shareable link for this gist. Not sure how else to do it. BTW ScriptLab is also saying that the coersion type (XmlSvg) is not supported. 
https://gist.github.com/ThomasHeron/038f463c41e095d1da11a4f3c56c0c0c

Comment: According to this, https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/requirement-sets/common/image-coercion-requirement-sets?view=excel-js-preview#imagecoercion-12, PowerPoint does support XmlSvg. Can you add a screenshot of the coercion type error to your question?

Comment: Exactly that's what I expect... I posted the code for the function in the original question along with a screenshot of the error I receive. Thanks!

Comment: I was able to open your gist in a browser and block copy it to Script Lab. I also get the "undefined" error, but I don't get the error about coercion type. Consider raising this as a a bug on the [office-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new/choose) repo.

Comment: Thanks Rick! I just reported this to the office-js repo as you suggested. The number is #3309 for anyone that might come across the same issue. https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/3309